# How to exclude bookmarks from ido virtual buffers?

Tags: ido, bookmarks

I just put `(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)` in my init file. It seems ido virtual buffers includes my bookmarks after I use `bookmark-jump`.

How could I make ido virtual buffers only includes  my recent files?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, but I don't know if it will break something.
So far, it works fine.

```el
(defadvice ido-add-virtual-buffers-to-list (around k--advice-remove-bookmarks activate)
  (let ((bookmark-alist ()))
    ad-do-it))
```

Equivalently, with the newer [`advice-add`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advice.html) mechanism:

```el
(define-advice ido-add-virtual-buffers-to-list
    (:around (fn &rest args) my-disable-bookmarks)
  "Call FN on ARGS with bookmarks temporarily disabled."
  (let ((bookmark-alist ()))
    (apply fn args)))
```